# How to use 'conflicts' with ruby trolloop

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, trollop

Hi I'm using trollop to parse my command line options in ruby, I have four mutually exclusive options, and one option is always required.

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to ensure only one of the four options is passed.  If called with more than one option I want the usage help (educate?) shown.

I see from the trollop source there's something called conflicts

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/trollop/2.1.2/Trollop/Parser#conflicts-instance_method

that sounds like it does what I want (?) but I can't figure out how to use it correctly.

My current stanza is effectively this

```
require 'trollop'
opts = Trollop::options do

  opt :last, "last"
  opt :first, "first"
  opt :file, "filename",
        :type => String
  opt :date, "date to read",
        :type => Date
end
Trollop::die :file, "must exist" unless File.exist?(opts[:file]) if opts[:file]
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `conflicts` as a line in your `do` block like this:

```
require 'trollop'
opts = Trollop::options(ARGV) do
  opt :last, "last"
  opt :first, "first"
  opt :file, "filename", :type => String
  opt :date, "date to read", :type => Date
  conflicts :last, :first
end

puts "Your Options Are: "
puts opts
```

Then you get the following output:

```
ruby test_options.rb  --last Last --first First
Error: --last conflicts with --first.
Try --help for help.
```